# MediaElement give wrong position or seek to wrong position with high bitrates audio files (.Net.Maui)

Tags: c#, maui, mediaelement

I just observed that MediaElement on .Net.Maui doesn't seek or get position correctly with flac files  (24Bit96000Hz). Has anyone else this same problem? Normal flac files (16Bit44000Hz) doesn't has any problems to seek or get correct position. Usually difference in time is about 14 sec per 4.14 minutes. MediaElement plays up to 4.28 min even track (file) is only 4.14 min long.

But if I reload (set) media source on every track (flac contains all album tracks) AND seek to the position any problem doesn't occurs.

Comment: Have you tested it on other devices? And how can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem so that we can test on our side?

Comment: So far tested on Windows only. I try on Android later today. It's easy to test: Use Flac-file with cue file; 16Bit44100Hz and 24Bit96000Hz and play them. The first one get play position correctly , second one not. From Cue file it's easy to find out real length&position of tracks. I tried many files so far and result always same (and other players give correct position)

Comment: Thanks for your support and feedback for Maui. For this problem, you can create a new issue [here](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues/new/choose).

Comment: Ok, tested on Android phone ; no problems. Looks like that problems occurs on Windows platform only.

Comment: Hi @Weissu, if you have created a new issue for this problem, please share the link you have created here. Thanks in advance. :)